# Bash script that creates a bash script with variables

Tags: bash, variables

I'm writing a Bash called "NewProject" that creates a second Bash script called "compile". Both scripts must be able to take arguments as input. My problem is that I can not write "$1" into the compile script - this simply copies the contents of NewProject's first argument into the compile script. This is the part of the NewProject script that creates the compile script.

```
echo "#!/bin/bash" > $1/compile
echo "
if [[ -z '$1' ]];
then
        echo "You are missing file names. Type in: compile -o executable files."
        exit 1
fi" >> $1/compile
chmod u+x $1/compile
```

And here is output from a test run of the NewProject script.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ -z 'testproject4' ]];

then
        echo You are missing file names. Type in: compile -o executable files.
        exit 1
fi
```

How can I change the NewProject script so that instead of `'testproject4'`, the compile script contains `'$1'`?

Comment: $ in "" gets interpreted, in '' it doesn't. Also note that you have internal " within your surrounding " (the "You are missing file names..." bit) which might not be what you intended (it doesn't matter in this case because echo echoes all its arguments separated by strings anyway)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a heredoc

```
cat <<'END' > "$1"/compile
#!/bin/bash

if [[ -z $1 ]];
then
        echo "You are missing file names. Type in: compile -o executable files."
        exit 1
fi
END
chmod u+x "$1"/compile
```

When you quote the heredoc terminator word (`cat <<'END'`), it effectively quotes the entire doc

Answer (score 3):

You should be more accurate with quoting.

```
echo "$1" >>$1/compile
```

will append the value of NewProject's first argument into the compile script.

However:

```
echo '$1' >>$1/compile
```

will append exactly `$1` characters into the compile script.

Comment: BTW: `echo "if [[ -z '$1' ]]; then echo "You are missing file names. Type in: compile -o executable files." exit 1 fi" >> $1/compile` will not work as you expect. Double quotes cannot be nested, so `echo "aa "bb cc dd" ee" >>$1/compile` will append `aa bb` `cc` `dd ee` (not `aa "bb cc dd" ee`) into compile. You should either escape inner `"`-s (`echo "aa \"bb cc dd\" ee" >>$1/compile`), or surround `"`-s with `'`-s.

Comment: To insert `$1` into compile, you can either use single quotes (`echo '$1' >...`) or escape `$` with backslash (`echo "\$1" >>...`).